# Minimum number of circles to cover n points

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

What is the minimum number of circles with radius r needed to cover all n points, while the n points are on a straight line?

I know that there is a similar question that was asked
before here.
[Minimum number of circles with radius r to cover n points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882202/minimum-number-of-circles-with-radius-r-to-cover-n-points)

My attempt : I'm trying to solve it in a linear time ,
I thought about this algorithm :

1. place the first circle in place that solve for the first point.
2. solve for the second point in the minimum number of circles by checking if the distance  between these two points is less than 2*r. and continue in the processes for all n-points.
   I think it's greedy algorithm , but is it optimal and linear?

Comment: How does your question differ from the earlier one?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the points are placed on a straight line.

Comment: Seems unlikely you could solve this in linear time if the points are not in sorted order and you expect the end result to look like groups of overlapping circles (O(n)) and gaps (O(n)) and you somehow need to keep track of those groups as you build it from an unsorted input. Have you been told it is possible in linear time?

Comment: @IanMercer Actually I was told so , and the points are in  sorted order , but the distance can be different between two neighbors.

Comment: Shouldnt the answer always be: `int(dist_between(first_pt, last_pt)/(2*r))` ?

Comment: Yes it is greedy, optimal and linear, given the points are sorted.

Comment: @Mahajna please update your question with the fact that they are _sorted_, that makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is, have your points in an array.

Iterate over each point adding the distance between it and the prior point, up and until the accumulated distance is more than 2r.

Add to a global counter one. reset the distance, repeat.

In pseudocode:

```
count = 1
last_point = point_list[0]
distance = 0
for(point in point_list)
   distance += norm(point - last_point)
   if(distance >= 2r)
     count++
     distance = 0
   last_point = point
```

## Proof

Base case:
It works for n = 1, trivially

Inductive case:
Assume it works for n up to k cases

Assume that a new point is introduced to the line.

Case 1, the point is within the interior of the last calculated circle. Then on the next iteration of the loop the condition in the if statement is not satisfied, the count doesn't go up, the algorithm returns the correct answer

Case 2, the point is outside the interior of the last calculated circle.
Then, since the covering for the other k elements was the minimum, it is impossible to rearrange the circles to cover the new point. So we must introduce a new circle.

In this case the condition of the if is satisfied, the count goes up by one. We return the correct number once again.

We have proven the inductive case.

## Verbose proof

You will have to accept the latex notation as is since stack overflow does not format latex.

Assume we have a set of points $P$. Assume that $d = max(||p_i - p_j||)$ where $p_i, p_j \in P$. If $d < 2r$ the $P \subset C$ for some disk $C$ of radius r.

Given a new point $q \notin P$ if $max(||q - p||) < 2r$ where $p \in P$ then $\exists$ a disk $D$ such that ${q} \cup P \ subset D$.

Otherwise if $max(||q - p||) > 2r$ then no such disk exists, otherwise there would be 2 points in the disk such that their distance is greater than 2r, which is absurd.

This is lemma 1.

Assume we have a set of such sets $S$, i.e. $s \in S \implies s = {x | ||x - y|| < 2r \text{if} y \in s}$. And for all $s \in S$ if $x \in s$ then $x \in L$ where $L$ is some line. Assume as well that if ${x \in s1 \in S}$ and $y \in s2 \in S$ then $||x_1 - x_2|| >= 2r$.

Since the points are on a, in a line by definition, $\exists x_0$ and $\vec{d}$ ($\vec{d}$ a unit vector), such that the points can be ordered relative to their distance to $x_0$, WLOG assume $x_0$ is one of the points in $S$, such that $\vec{d} \cdot (x - x_0) \geq 0$ where $x \in s \in S$.

This implies that for each set $s_i \in S \exists D_i$ such that $s_i \ subset D_i$ and $D_i \cap D_j = \empty$ if $i \neq j$, by construction. And that the disks ${D_i}$ are well ordered.

Let $s_{max} \in S$ be the set such that $\vec{d} \cdot (x_{max} - x_0) \geq \vec{d} \cdot (x_i - x_0)$ where $x_{max} \in s_max$ and $x \in s \in S$ for all such $x$. Or in plain english, $s_max$ is the set containing the point furthest from $x_0$.

Assume a new point $q$ is now added to the line such that its distance to $x_0$ is larger than that of $x_max$.

By lemma 1, either the total number of circles remains constant or it goes up by 1, and will only go up by one if $max(||q - x||) >= 2r$ where $x \in s_{max}$.

this is lemma 2.

Refer then to the algorithm described in the prior section.
Whenever a sequence of consecutive points spans less than $2r$, $\exists D$ a disk containing those points (by the prior argument). If a new point in the sequence is found such that its distance to the furthest point from it is more than $2r$ then one additional circle is needed (again by lemma 1).

Lemma 2 postulates that to know if a new circle is needed we only need to focus on the last set of points, provided we have visited the points (and thus the sets) in order. If a new point is less than 2r within distance of the farthest point in the last set, no new circle is needed, otherwise a new one is needed (by lemma 1) And we thus focus on this new point (and its associated set).

We do this until all points have been visited.

We have successfully proven that the algorithm is minimal.

(And that we do not need to care where the circles are :^))

Comment: this is not the minimum number if the distance between every two points is not equal. for example if the first point is 2*r + 1 from the second point and all the points except for the last one can be covered in one circle and the last one is very far from the other points.

Comment: this is a linear time algorithm , but does it provide minimum number of circles ?

Comment: In my opinion it should be > 2r and not >=. Then it is garanteed the minimum number of circles (if the points are ordered of course, otherwise not).

Comment: That is splitting hairs OP has a point, I am not entirely sure this is finding the minimum. I think it is but I have not proven it.

Comment: You need to say WHERE you introduce the new circle, presumably so that the new point is on one edge of it and it covers the next 2r of the line, otherwise it's not optimal going forward.

Comment: I do not, read the code carefuly, I dont use any ifnormation about the circles other than their diameter, which means that the circle is always wherever it maximizes local coverage of the points.

Comment: In your PROOF you say "So we must introduce a new circle". That's not a proof as written.

Comment: I say we introduce a new circle I do not specify where on the line the circle is. Because that's irrelevant. A circle spans exactly a distance of 2r. 

that means that as long as the sum of distances of consecutive points is < 2r a circle can contain all of them.

Look at the loop I have written. There is no reference to the center of the circle, it is merely asking, do all the points I have seen fit within one circle?

If yes, then there's no need for a new circle. However if a new point is found that is too far away from the others, then a new circle is needed.

Comment: You are thinking about the problem too much like an engineer, which I appreciate, but where the circle is is irrelevant. All that matters is how many points can be placed together in clusters of 2r. 

Specifying where the circle is would just add uneeded verbosity to the proof.

If you really want a visualization to make it easier to understand, just slide the circle along the line up and until the first point contained inside of it ends up in it's boundary.

You could construct the proof like that, but you would not gain correctness and it would be harder to write and understand.

Comment: I just graduated with a double major and did pretty well in my pure math courses, I am confident the proof I wrote is fine.

Comment: @IanMercer Are you satisfied with this explanation?

Comment: No. Unless you place the circle in the correct position at the end of the iteration it is not true that you cannot "rearrange the circles to cover the new point". The proof switches between talking about "last calculated circle" as if that's fixed at the end of the iteration and deciding that you later slide it over to have the left edge on the leftmost point in the set. The last calculated circle needs to be as far 'right' as possible otherwise the set will not be minimal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224274/discussion-between-makogan-and-ian-mercer).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to provide a better proof, hopefully this will  be satisfactory : ) and explain why there is no need to tell where the circles are.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can do on linear time but O(n*logn).

Since they are on the same line, I would set one of them as reference point (`0`) and add them in an array based on their distance to the reference point. Now 2D positions are converted to 1D.

Then sort them (`O(n*logn)`). Then iterate over them by putting the leftmost position of the circle on top of the current point.

For example, after sorting the positions of the points are  `-3 -2, 0, 1, 2, 10` and let's say `r=1`.

First circle will cover from `-3 to -1`, second one `0 to 2` and the last one will be from `10 to 12`. So 3 circles will be used.

Notice that, this algorithm doesn't assume the numbers and distances are integer. Just for the sake of simplicity, I used integers.

Comment: It can absolutely be done in linear time provided the points are ordered.

Comment: @Makogan Given that the points are ordered, the algorithm above is already linear time. But problem statement is not saying the points are ordered.